# Не понятен паттерн конструктора

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В примерах по AngularJS, которые используют сервисы всегда демонстрируют такой паттерн:

```
module.factory('myFactory', function($log) {
    var myFactory = {
        this.getLog = function () {
            console.log('Bla bla bla')
        }
    };
    return myFactory;
});
```

Не могу понять почему не сделать вот так:

```
module.factory('myFactory', function($log) {
    return {
        this.getLog = function () {
            console.log('Bla bla bla')
        }
    };
});
```

Зачем нужен этот бесполезный var **myFactory**?

Comment: Код в вопросе синтаксически некорректен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это скорее всего дело стилистики: возвращать что-либо как есть либо через промежуточную переменную. Использование промежуточной переменной потенциально делает код гибче на случай добавления функционала и дружелюбным к отладке, когда точку остановки можно будет поставить сразу после переменной. На мой взгляд переменными оперировать удобнее, чем анонимными объектами или результатами вызовов. В данном случае, если например фабрику нужно будет расширить миксинами или пронаследовать от другого объекта, то удобнее это будет сделать с использованием переменной. Хочу поделиться еще одним вариантом, который описывается в [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#accessible-members-up-top):

```
module.factory('myFactory', function($log) {

    var myFactory = {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    };

    return myFactory;
    ////////

    function foo() {
        console.log('foo');
    }

    function bar() {
        console.log('bar');
    }
}
```

Плюс в том, что размещение публичного интерфейса сверху делает код фабрики читаемее и позволяет сразу увидеть все, с чем она позволяет работать + сразу видно то, что нужно покрывать тестами. Это особенно полезно тогда, когда код фабрики разрастается и приходится скроллить, чтобы понять, что вообще в ней есть. Применим этот подход не только к фабрике, но и контроллерам, директивам и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ.
Да, удобный способ обозначить API. Начинаю иметь в виду )

Comment: А мне этот подход не нравится. Получается охапка функций, которые непонятно к чему относятся. А ещё, в большинстве случаев, при использовании подобного подхода теряется возможность переопределения методов, хотя к фабрикам это не относится, поскольку переопределять их методы было бы странно.

Answer (score 2):

Просто чтобы была переменная вместо this.

Я бы не стал так делать, если в этом нет необходимости.

Answer (score -1):

По моему написав имя переменной можно повысить читаемость кода, и не нужно будет писать комментарий, хотя в примерах встречал пишут по разному фабрики
Я пишу как то так, встретил в примерах мне понравилось

```
gameServices.factory('Content', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var service = function() {
            this.items = [];          
        };
    service.prototype.nextPage = function(callback) {
//Тут загрузка контента
    }
        return service;
    }
]);
```